# missing hour in seq function generating time in R?

Tags: r, time, posixct, seq

I have a problem in generating proper time sequence using R:

```
fivemin <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014/01/01 0:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2014/04/01 0:00:00"), by="5 mins",tz="EST")
time <- data.frame(MasterTime=fivemin)
```

Using above code, I can get a data frame with 25909 observations. However, under Eastern Standard Time (without daylight saving), the number of observations should be 25920. The difference is 1 hour from the transition of daylight saving time on 03/09/20014, because then the time would change from 1 AM to 3 AM directly. I'm not sure how R deals with this kind of time change. How can I revise my code so R produce a time sequence without that missing 2AM hour on 03/09/2014? Does anyone have any idea on this?

Really thanks!

Comment: Set the time zone explicitly in `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: You could also ignore daylight savings for the duration of the session with `Sys.setenv(TZ='EST')`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use daylight saving time try setting tz = 'UTC'

```
fivemin <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014/01/01 0:00:00", tz = 'UTC'), as.POSIXct("2014/04/01 0:00:00", tz = 'UTC'), by="5 mins")
head(fivemin)
length(fivemin)
#[1] 25921
```

Apart from 'UTC' or 'GMT' it's better not to use the three letter designation for a timezone e.g "EST" because these are ambiguous.  Australia has an Eastern Standard Time, as does the US. Instead use Country/City

```
fivemin <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 2:00:00", tz="Australia/Melbourne"), as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 3:00:00", tz="Australia/Melbourne"), by="5 mins")
length(fivemin)
# [1] 25   
# Melbourne's DST finished on 6 April 2014 at 3 am so there are 25 x 5 min periods in the hour between 2am and 3 am 


fivemin <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 2:00:00", tz="Australia/Brisbane"), as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 3:00:00", tz="Australia/Brisbane"), by="5 mins")
length(fivemin)
# [1] 13  Brisbane doesn't use DST so no problem
```

Also check the dst function in the [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) package.

If you would like to retain the time zone, but use standard time, try something like.

```
library(lubridate)
fivemin <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 2:00:00", tz="Australia/Melbourne"), as.POSIXct("2014-04-06 3:00:00", tz="Australia/Melbourne"), by="5 mins")
fivemin[dst(fivemin)] <- fivemin[dst(fivemin)]-3600
```